# Lightning design css overwrites header styling

Tags: css, slds, stylesheets, style

When using the latest lightning design css on a visualforce page the styling overwrites the standard styling in the header. Is there any way around this happening?

Comment: How are you adding SLDS to your page?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the original css file that is in your static resources and change the css for the header. If you do this, it will affect it everywhere it is used.

Another option, which is considered a hack and not a best practice is to use the style tag after you import all style sheets and override the styling. This works but as you make more pages becomes a nightmare and anyone working after you will curse your name.

Another route is to use JavaScript to change styling. This may work when you want to use this for only some pages. You can create the script and then save it to Static Resources and then call in on VF pages  you need it on. This is pretty clean.

Just remember to run JavaScript after you have loaded the CSS files. This is actually pretty easy if you have not done before. You can find it on W3 Schools.

below is one example. I do the 3rd method most of the time.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontfamily.asp